# Футурологическая лингвистика

Tags: общие-вопросы

Подскажите научные труды, статьи, посвящённые вопросу дальнейшего развития языка и возможным его изменениям в будущем. Сама никак не могу найти.

Comment: http://rikmosgu.ru/publications/3559/4423/

Comment: http://www.topos.ru/veer/11/v11_iazyk_epst.html

Comment: http://www.km.ru/referats/8BF54FB979E5412C8DCE47DCBE55A6C6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**По данной теме можно найти информацию в следующих книгах:**

1) Панов М.В. О некоторых общих тенденциях в развитии русского литературного языка XX в. // Вопросы языкознания, 1963, № 1.

2) Ильина Н.Е. Рост аналитизма в морфологии // Русский язык конца XX столетия (1985–1995). – М., 1996.

3) Русский язык и современность. Проблемы и перспективы развития русистики. Тезисы конференции 20-23 мая 1991 г. – М., 1991 (обзор тезисов см. также в кн.: В.Г.Костомаров. Языковой вкус эпохи).

4) Серебренников Б.А. Об относительной самостоятельности развития системы языка. – М., 1968.

5) И. А. Стернин «Социальные факторы и развитие современного русского языка»